# Uncaught type error says function can not be applied to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error when I am trying to replace certain text with other certain text with javascript / jquery.

Here is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'html'

and here are the lines of javascript on the site:

```
$(document).ready({
   var navigationLinks = $('.nav a');
        for(var i=0; i < navigationLinks.length; i++){
             var thisLink = navigationLinks[i];
             switch(thisLink.html()){
                case "About":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;');

                case "Work":
                     thisLink.html().replace(/Work/g,'&#xe010');

                case "CV":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/CV/g,'&#xe00c');

                case "Resume":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/Resume/g,'&#xe00d;');

                case "down":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/down/g,'&#xe00d;');

                case "Mail":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/Mail/g,'&#xe011;');

                case "Dribbble":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/Dribbble/g,'&#xe015;');

                 case "GooglePlus":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/GooglePlus/g,'&#xe012;');

                case "Facebook":
                    thisLink.html().replace(/Facebook/g,'&#xe013;');

                case "Twitter":
                   thisLink.html().replace(/Twitter/g,'&#xe014');

                default:
                   thisLink.html().replace(thisLink.html(),thisLink.html());
        }
    }
    window.onscroll=scrollFunc;
});
```

Comment: Use `navigationLinks.each()` instead of `for`

Comment: `var thisLink = $(navigationLinks[i]);` jQuery objects and native JS elements are not the same.

Comment: @adeneo: unwrap DOM from jquery object then wrap it back in the same line... Looks weird )

Comment: @adeneo, why not `.eq(i)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
navigationLinks[i]; // DOM element which doesn't have an `html` function
```

To:

```
navigationLinks.eq(i);// jQuery wrapper which does have an `html` function
```

Comment: Your solution made sense. But the script is still not working. None of the text is the anchors is being replaced. It is the original text. The error is gone, but the code is not working.

Comment: @ArashDonsaliKapoor, `replace` doesn't modified the string but returns a new string, you need to assign the returned string like so: `thisLink.html(thisLink.html().replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;'));`

Answer (score 0):

.html() is a jquery method. You want

```
$(thislink).html()
```